# Python equivalent to Bash $()

Tags: python, equivalent

I search the Python equivalent for the following Bash code:

```
VAR=$(echo $VAR)
```

Pseudo Python code could be:

```
var = print var
```

Can you help? :-)

Regards

Edit:

I search a way to do this:

```
for dhIP in open('dh-ips.txt', 'r'):
    gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
    print gi.country_code_by_addr(print dhIP) # <-- this line is my problem
```

In Bash i would do it like this:

print gi.country_code_by_addr($(dhIP)) # only pseudo code...

Hope it's more clear now.

Edit2:

Thank you all! Here's my solution which works. Thanks to Liquid_Fire for the remark with the newline char and thanks to hop for his code!

```
import GeoIP

fp = open('dh-ips.txt', 'r')
gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)

try:
    for dhIP in fp:
        print gi.country_code_by_addr(dhIP.rstrip("\n"))
finally:
    fp.close()
```

Comment: what do you _actually_ want to do?

Comment: what do you think that bash code does? eg: `VAR="-e"` or `VAR="a   b"`(I have no idea how to format the multiple spaces there). what do you really want to do?

Comment: Are you trying to assign the output of a command line program to a variable?  Or perhaps grab the value of an environment variable?

Comment: PS I don't know why everyone was downvoting the person who suggested eval, that is literally what the $() syntax is (sort of).

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @mootinator: no, `$()` isn't like eval at all.

Comment: @yi_H They both take an arbitrary command (in their native language) and return a result (the vast differences between how the commands are processed/where the output actually comes from, etc isn't really all that important).  But this isn't really the place for that discussion, come smack my opinion down on MSO chat if you want :P.

Comment: `var='echo $(ls)'`. Yes, I'm saying that, as it's name says, eval does full evaluation. It's really a quite different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `dhIP` as it is. There is no need to do anything special with it:

```
for dhIP in open('dh-ips.txt', 'r'):
    gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
    print gi.country_code_by_addr(dhIP)
```

NB: There are some other issues with your code.

Without being familiar with the library you use, it seems to me that you unnecessarily instantiate GeoIP in every iteration of the loop. Also, you should not throw away the file handle, so you can close the file afterwards.

```
fp = open('dh-ips.txt', 'r')
gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)

try:
    for dhIP in fp:
        print gi.country_code_by_addr(dhIP)
finally:
    fp.close()
```

Or, even better, in 2.5 and above you can use a context manager:

```
with open('dh-ips.txt', 'r') as fp:
    gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
    for dhIP in fp:
        print gi.country_code_by_addr(dhIP)
```

Comment: Thank you! Together with rstrip("\n") it works like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `print` in there, just use the name of the variable:

```
for dhIP in open('dh-ips.txt', 'r'):
    gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
    print gi.country_code_by_addr(dhIP)
```

Also note that iterating through a file object gives you lines with the newline characters at the end. You may want to use something like `dhIP.rstrip("\n")` to remove them before passing it on to `country_code_by_addr`.

Comment: rstrip("\n") is needed! I used your remark together with the code from hop and now it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try these functions:

str(var)

repr(var)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to reassign a value to the same name it would be:

```
var = var
```

Now if you're trying to assign the string representation (which is usually what `print` returns) of whatever object is referred to by `var`:

```
var = str(var)
```

Is that what you're after?